# JavaScript: Get DOM elements inside Vue.js modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs2

I use [Vue.js modal](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal) inside my Vue app. It's part of a Vue component. The template part consists of the modal only:

```
<template>
    <!-- Modal: Edit exercise -->
    <modal name='edit-exercise-modal'
           :draggable='true'
           height='auto'>

        <form @submit.prevent='storeEdits'>
            <div ref='myDiv'>Some text</div>
            <!-- Also tried:
            <div id='my-div'>Some text</div>
            -->
        </form>

    </modal>
</template>
```

I need to access DOM elements to user the [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) library and highlight some text inside `my-div`. But whenever I try to get it in a method, I get `undefined` or `null` instead, depending on whether I use pure JS or Vue refs:

```
console.log(this.$refs.myDiv); // undefined
console.log(document.getElementById('my-div'); // null
```

When I do `console.log(this.$refs`), I get `myDiv` inside the `refs` property. But when I stop code execution with `debugger` directly after `console.log`, `refs` seems to be empty.

What's the problem here? What can I do to get a reference to the `div` I need to modify?

*edit: Here's a more complete snippet*

```js
<template>
    <!-- Modal: Edit exercise -->
    <modal name='edit-exercise-modal'
           :draggable='true'
           height='auto'>

        <form @submit.prevent='storeEdits'>
            <div ref='myDiv'>Some text</div>
            <!-- Also tried:
            <div id='my-div'>Some text</div>
            -->
        </form>

    </modal>
</template>

<script>

    import Vue from 'vue';

    import VModal from 'vue-js-modal';
    Vue.use(VModal);

    import rangy from 'rangy';
    import 'rangy/lib/rangy-classapplier';

    export default {

        props: [ 'exercise' ],

        /**********************************************
        ********************* Data ********************
        **********************************************/

        data: function() {
            return {
                selected:    [],
                category_id: undefined,
                text:        undefined,
                mistakes:    undefined
            };
        },


        /**********************************************
        ******************** Methods ******************
        **********************************************/

        methods: {
            sampleMethod: function() {
                console.log(this.$refs.textWithMistakes);
                console.log(document.getElementById('text-with-mistakes'));
            }
        },


        /**********************************************
        ******************* Watchers ******************
        **********************************************/

        watch: {
            /**
             * Sets up and shows modal when exercise data is loaded from parent.
             */
            exercise: function() {
                this.category_id = this.exercise.category_id;
                this.text = this.exercise.text;
                this.mistakes = this.exercise.mistakes;

                this.$modal.show('edit-mistakes-exercise-modal');

                // Not working
                this.applyClass(sampleMethod);
                
                // Working, but not a way I'd like to go
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.applyClass(sampleMethod);;
                }, 3000);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There is no closing quote for your ref `<div ref='myDiv>`

Comment: Thanks, that was just a typo in Stackoverflow.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have your div in DOM at moment when `console.log` `$refs`. It would be very helpful to us if you can provide snippet of code where you log refs along with the modal component.

Comment: Thanks, I added a snippet. As you can see, everything is working when I delay the function call using `setTimeout`, but that feels like a hacky solution.

Comment: Did you try this.$nextTick()?

Comment: I did, but it didn't have any visible effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content inside the modal is not accessible for you as long as the modal is closed. But the `vue-js-modal` component emits an 'opened' event when the modal is toggled visible. You can call your code the when modal is open and finished rendering.

```
<modal 
  name='edit-exercise-modal'
  @opened="onModalOpened"
  :draggable='true'
  height='auto'
>
   ...
</modal>
```

Comment: 1: This does not apply, at least there's no `v-if` inside the template. 2: I don't understand this approach. When should I emit an event, how should I handle it? 3: I do pass the data as a prop, it's just that just before the modal opens, this data is undefined. There's a watcher on this prop which shows the modal when the prop changes. So I understand why `setTimeout` solves my problem, I just need a solution without having to guess the interval I need to wait.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that the modal is not your own code. Look at this: https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal/blob/master/src/Modal.vue#L25 That's `v-if` I was talking about. It means, that the HTML inside the modal is not there until the modal is visible.

Comment: Option 2 could be a solution: https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal/blob/master/src/Modal.vue#L524 An event gets emitted when the modal is opened. `<modal @opened="onModalOpened">`

Comment: `@opened` solved my problem. I was actually aware of this event, but I was confused because in my case the modal is inside a nested component and I thought this event couldn't help me. Thanks!